# Query Posts or Get Posts by custom fields, possible?

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, get-posts

If I were to take a standard query post.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=payment'); while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
```

Only this time I would like to query the post by 2 custom fields that it may contain.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=payment'.get_post_meta($post->ID,'bookingref', true).get_post_meta($post->ID,'customerref', true) ); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

That doesn't work. Is something like this possible and how is it done?

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To  query posts by custom fields you can use the 'meta_query' parameter

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'payment',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'bookingref',
                'value' => 'the_value_you_want',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'customerref',
                'value' => 'the_value_you_want',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
    )
);
query_posts($args); while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

you can't use get_post_meta inside the query because it gets you the value and not the key and also it accepts a Post ID to get that value of and before the query $post->id is not in the scope.

Comment: yup, this is better than my (deleted) answer - meta_query is the way to go for multiple custom key querying

Comment: Marvellous well done. You are missing a bracket though. You need ..  )); query_posts($args)  ..

Comment: There's a big opportunity here to educate, using WP_Query, and the performance costs of meta queries